About filtration of the Leray-Serre spectral sequence
In the following proof, it is used the spectral sequence of the Borel
fibration $X\longrightarrow X_{T}\longrightarrow B_{T}$.
I don't understand how the map $\psi $ is obtained, and how is it an $R$-module homomorphism?
Here $R=H^{\ast }\left( B_{T}\right) $.
I think I have a problem with the filtration of $H^{*}_T(X)$. Can someone explain that
to me?
For more see A question about the Leray-Serre spectral sequence of the Borel fibration


I suggest reading this in the book by Bott and Tu, or in the notes on Alan Hatcher's homepage.
